# Ticklabels in matplotlib don't match the plot values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working the following plot:

[image]

For wich I'm using the following code:

```
testy = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]


probs = [0. , 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0.9, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1, 1. , 0. , 0. ,
       0.9, 1. , 0. , 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0.1, 1. ,
       0. , 0. , 0.9, 0. , 0.9, 0. , 1. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 1. , 0. , 1. ,
       0. , 0. , 0. , 0.9, 0. , 1. ]

def plot_roc_curve(testy, probs,data_dir=''):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(testy, probs)    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(fpr*100, tpr*100, color='black', marker='.')
    ax.plot([0, 100], [0, 100], color='darkblue', linestyle='--')
    ax.set_title('ROC Curve',fontweight='bold',loc='left')
    ax.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate',fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate',fontweight='bold')





plot_roc_curve(testy, probs,data_dir='')
```

I want to modify the plot to add the  '%' symbol as 80%, 100%...

for that, I have the following code:

```
def plot_roc_curve(testy, probs,data_dir=''):
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(testy, probs)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(fpr*100, tpr*100, color='black', marker='.')
    ax.plot([0, 100], [0, 100], color='darkblue', linestyle='--')
    ax.set_title('ROC Curve',fontweight='bold',loc='left')
    ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in fpr])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['{:,.2%}'.format(x) for x in fpr])
    ax.set_xlabel('False Positive Rate',fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_ylabel('True Positive Rate',fontweight='bold')


plot_roc_curve(testy, probs)
```

But this breaks the code, since the label does not match the points:

[image]

Comment: Never use `ax.set_yticklabels` without controling the positions of the ticks as well. Better solutions are shown in the duplicate.

Comment: The question was closed while I was writing an answer. To put it simply, use `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter())` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter())` instead of `ax.set_yticklabels` and `ax.set_xticklabels`

Comment: @politicalscientist thanks, it worked perfectly

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sure really nice to close question, thanks mate (y)

Comment: This is what an answer to the duplicate tells you, so you're not missing anything by having this closed as duplicate.